# how to avoid a date alteration with pd.to_excel() method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the excel file `city.xlsx` created with this code I got this strange value for the date : `2021-04-91`

How to avoid that?

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame('Brussels',index=[pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01')],columns=['CITY'])
df.to_excel('city.xlsx')
```

One Day Later, after kind comment from Pkumar . . .
I found what is wrong. The issue comes with the excel viewer inside somes apps (my ftp, Dropbox and so on...) The date in the excel file itself appears correctly.

Comment: Its incorrect, the date is coming fine : `2021-04-01 00:00:00` which is the ISO format of date. Not sure what is happening at your end

Comment: You 're right. I found what is wrong. The issue comes with the excel viewer inside somes apps (my ftp, Dropbox  and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.
The issue comes with the excel viewer inside somes apps (my ftp, Dropbox and so on...).
The date inside the Excel file itself is quite correct.